# What use are the Align and Anchor properties on TForm?

Tags: forms, delphi, alignment

It's possible to set the Alignment on a TForm, say set one form to alTop and another to alClient - whereby the two forms take up the whole screen area in the obvious way.  Is this a sensible thing to do in an application?

I also notice that anchors are exposed on forms - but I can't think what they would be useful for (resolution changes? MDI apps?)  Any ideas?

Edit:
I've made a [video about this post](http://youtu.be/Jdf5JVAXb0Q) to make things clearer.

Comment: You could mimic a taskbar on the edge of the desktop, by setting `Align` to, say, `alTop'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `TForm` like an ordinary control by setting its `Parent` property:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmEmbed:= TForm.Create(Self);
  frmEmbed.Parent:= Self;
  frmEmbed.Width:= 50;
  frmEmbed.Height:= 50;
  frmEmbed.Align:= alRight;
  frmEmbed.Anchors:= [akLeft, akBottom];
  frmEmbed.Visible:= True;
end;
```

you should comment `frmEmbed.Align:= alRight;` line to see how `Anchors` property works.

---

If you are interested where the above is used: parented form without a caption bar is an alternative to `TFrame`; frames were not available with early Delphi versions, so parented forms were used instead. You can find them in legacy code.

Comment: I still use embedded forms in current code.  Is there any reason that re-parenting forms should be limited to legacy code?  I find it easier to split complex forms (usually different tab sheets) into multiple forms instead of frames.  It helps me keep my logic split and limits the number of controls I have on any one form.  Normally I set the parent to the tab sheet and set Align := alClient.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a Form inside another Form. Dunno how good that would work though. In Delphi1 times there were special 3rd-party controls to route the event. Today it seems to more or less work out of the box, except for modal dialogs. Try like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(...);
begin
  with TForm.Create(Self) do begin
       Caption := 'Internal one';
       Parent := Self;
       Visible := True;
  end;    
end;
```

Perhaps anchors and align would make sense in this setup.
Afterall this seems how new "one-window" IDE layout is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

One simple case is for a captionless form (e.g. win-8 metropolis style) you can anchor an exit button to upper right corner.

But the best use is to simplify making a complex form responsive to size changes...
Using the akLeft and akRight, you can make a horizontal control fill space horizontally.  Using all 4 anchors is similar to setting a client to alclient, just without needing to surround it with other panels.

Much of what you can do with anchors can also be done with many panels, but as the form becomes more complex it will get messy sometimes requiring several levels of panels upon panels.

Of course using a combination of panels and anchors will often be the best answer.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question somewhat.  I'm really after the usefulness of Anchors / Alignment properties on the TForm class, i.e. to position the form on the screen - rather than using it to position controls on forms.

Comment: you might want to withdraw the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a form inside any other container component.

That's useful for docking, f.i. you can dock forms in a page control tabs, or anywhere really.

That's also useful as an alternative to TFrame: if you design a frame as a TForm rather than a TFrame, it won't be embeddable at design-time, and thus can't be edited/sabotaged by the design-time editor.

Embedded TFrames can have their properties or events redefined in the form where they're embedded, and that isn't always desirable or practical, especially when you want the frame to be easily upgradable or refactorable. Changed embbedded frame properties end up in the DFM, not the PAS, and so aren't seen at compile-time, and aren't simple to refactor/rename/etc.